# Using Ubuntu's built in screenshotting in a software?

Tags: command-line, screenshot

I'm wondering if it's possible to access these functions:

[image: screenshot]

Basically - My (C#) software triggers one of these screenshot functions and I want it to know where it's stored so I can use those pictures in my program

I'm on 21.10 if it matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu uses this command.
$ gnome-screenshot -w

With the dconf-editor you should be able to set an other path.
(/org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/auto-save-directory)

Under XUbuntu 21.10 you can use this command in a script to make screenshots:

xfce4-screenshooter -f -s /home/billy/Screenshots/"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M_%S").png"

You should be able to install and use this xfce4 program for Ubuntu (gnome) too.

Comment: This does not answer the question, "where the screenshots are stored?"

Comment: Edit:
In addition to your 'gnome-screenshot -w', there's an option -f which specifies the file name. 
I did not know it could be triggered that way.
Thank you so much for helping me out, man.
Also, don't see why Panjeet is being a hater here. I left you an upvote, I hope you have a nice day generous sir.

Comment: I was locking at the Man-Page of  gnome-screenshot (https://linux.die.net/man/1/gnome-screenshot) and could not find any possibility to specify the path or filename. :-/  Because of this I want to point you at the other possibility, you can try this xfce4 program, try to install and use it.  With "gnome-screenshot --interactive" a user-interface will pop up and ask you for the path and filename. But do you want this or do you only want to make a full-screen picture with out any additional user activity?